# Puzzled with linux smc91cx driver code and related datasheet?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning the kernel(linux-3.1) network driver, the card driver is smc91cx, and I have the datasheet of SMSC lan91c111 by hand, so does the data sheet match the code? If so, I have some questions about the driver code:

```
static int smc_hard_start_xmit(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev)    {
    struct smc_local *lp = netdev_priv(dev);
void __iomem *ioaddr = lp->base;
unsigned int numPages, poll_count, status;
unsigned long flags;



DBG(3, "%s: %s\n", dev->name, __func__);

BUG_ON(lp->pending_tx_skb != NULL);

/*
 * The MMU wants the number of pages to be the number of 256 bytes
 * 'pages', minus 1 (since a packet can't ever have 0 pages :))
 *
 * The 91C111 ignores the size bits, but earlier models don't.
 *
 * Pkt size for allocating is data length +6 (for additional status
 * words, length and ctl)
 *
 * If odd size then last byte is included in ctl word.
 */
numPages = ((skb->len & ~1) + (6 - 1)) >> 8;
if (unlikely(numPages > 7)) {
    printk("%s: Far too big packet error.\n", dev->name);
    dev->stats.tx_errors++;
    dev->stats.tx_dropped++;
    dev_kfree_skb(skb);
    return NETDEV_TX_OK;
}

smc_special_lock(&lp->lock, flags);

/* now, try to allocate the memory */
SMC_SET_MMU_CMD(lp, MC_ALLOC | numPages); // why?
//  SMC_SET_MMU_CMD(lp, MC_ALLOC); // also work well 

/*
 * Poll the chip for a short amount of time in case the
 * allocation succeeds quickly.
 */
poll_count = MEMORY_WAIT_TIME;
do {
    status = SMC_GET_INT(lp);
    if (status & IM_ALLOC_INT) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "SMC91X: status & IM_ALLOC_INT\n");
        SMC_ACK_INT(lp, IM_ALLOC_INT);
        status = SMC_GET_INT(lp);
        if (status & IM_ALLOC_INT)
            printk(KERN_INFO "SMC91X: SMC_ACK_INT done.\n");
        break;
    }
} while (--poll_count);

smc_special_unlock(&lp->lock, flags);

lp->pending_tx_skb = skb;
if (!poll_count) {
    /* oh well, wait until the chip finds memory later */
    netif_stop_queue(dev);
    DBG(2, "%s: TX memory allocation deferred.\n", dev->name);
    SMC_ENABLE_INT(lp, IM_ALLOC_INT);
} else {
    /*
     * Allocation succeeded: push packet to the chip's own memory
     * immediately.
     */
    smc_hardware_send_pkt((unsigned long)dev);
}

return NETDEV_TX_OK;
}
```

See the code snip, I add some test code, I am puzzled with     `SMC_SET_MMU_CMD(lp, MC_ALLOC | numPages);` 
this macro finally set the mmu command register of smc91c111 card, It's just allowed 3-bits operation code, but why add numPages?

The next line is:
`SMC_ACK_INT(lp, IM_ALLOC_INT);`
this macro finally set the Bank2 - Interrupt Status Registers, the datasheet does not show ALLOC INT can be writable, so any tips?

Comment: I hope that the datasheet is matched with the driver code, so any tips?

Comment: Datasheets *never* match real code. There's always some bug/complication with the real hardware vs what the designers wanted.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I know these bug/complication? When I can't find comments to explain this in the code or detail from datasheet, what can I reference to? If I want to write driver code for some type card, and the datasheet don't gave me a clear definition, how can I realize it? So does the author of smc91cx driver?

Comment: Normally that knowledge is held by the people who wrote the code - either they're the people who deviated from the original plan, or they're people who found out the hard way and asked those that know.

Comment: Oh, my god! Thanks again, but it's somewhat unfair to the general reader to this driver code, although it open the datasheet, open the code but "close" some detailed but key parts, that's unlucky, anyhow.

Comment: This code matches the datasheet though.

Answer (score 2):

The smc91x.c driver covers both 91c111 and older chips. "The 91C111 ignores the size bits, but earlier models don't." Thus,

```
SMC_SET_MMU_CMD(lp, MC_ALLOC | numPages); // why?
```

and

```
SMC_SET_MMU_CMD(lp, MC_ALLOC); // also work well
```

both work for a 91c111. However, 91c90/c92/c94/c95/c100 may require numPages to be passed in. On 91c111, the bits used for numPages are marked as 'reserved', but it's possible that 'ignored' is a closer term.

As for

```
SMC_ACK_INT(lp, IM_ALLOC_INT);
```

The way the documentation shows the Interrupt Status Register(ISR) might be a bit confusing the first time you've worked with this style of datasheet. If you look at the 'offset' column in the datasheet, you'll notice the Interrupt Acknowledge Register(IAR) is also at 0xC, meaning that address is shared,but behaves differently based on a read or a write. Specifically, because the bits in IAR mirror those in ISR, this is also known as a Write-One-To-Clear-Register(use "W1C register" in google).

If ISR/IAR were instead a single, read-write register, it opens up a race condition where the kernel might read ISR, clear a bit in it, and just before storing it back to ISR, the hardware sets another bit in ISR, then the kernel overwrite ISR with its now stale copy.